# Working with variables outside of jquery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a .each that loops through table rows and compares information already entered to what the user is currently attempting to add. I have conditionals in the loop that look for duplicate entries across each of the s in the row. Depending on how many match, there's a yes/no decision for the user to make. If the user chooses yes, the current row needs to be removed. I am using jQuery UI and am having problems getting the dialog box to know what row to remove, or having the .each loop know what was selected in the dialog. 
The .each loop looks like this:

```
$('#tblSelectedList > tbody > tr').each(function() {
```

Here's the code for the dialog (within in the for loop):

```
                $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                .html('<div><h6>Delete duplicate?</h6></div>')
                .dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    title: 'Delete message',
                    zIndex: 10000,
                    autoOpen: true,
                    width: 'auto',
                    resizable: false,
                    buttons: {
                        Yes: function () {
                            removeThis = 1;
                            blnAdd = 1;
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        No: function () {
                            blnAdd = 0;
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });
```

and the method I am using to remove rows:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(7,$(this).attr('id').length);
$('#tblSelectedList #row-'+id).remove();
```

Everything works independently, but I can't get the dialog and its containing .each loop to know what the other is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing you need to do is to set an id for each row in your table. That way you can know how to find a row later on. That can be easily done using jQuery if it is not possible to do it when creating the actual table.

Here is an example:

```
var rowsCount = 0;
$('#tblSelectedList > tbody > tr').each(function() {
   //setting the row ids to be something like: tblSelectedList_row0,tblSelectedList_row1,...,tblSelectedList_rown
   $(this).attr("id","tblSelectedList_row" + (rowsCount++));
}
```

So then in your foreach loop for your actuall row dupplicate detaction logic you just do something like this:

```
$('#tblSelectedList > tbody > tr').each(function() {
       //determine here is this row should be deleted
       var rowShouldBeDeleted = true; 
    if ( rowShouldBeDeleted ){
        //here we invoke our promt for delete function passing the row identifier
        //which is explained below
        promptForDelete(this.id);
    }
}
```

Then I would suggest using two functions:

1. One that will ask the question "promtForDelete".
2. Another one that actually deletes the row.

So for the first one you need to pass all the information required to identify which row should be deleted "the row id", in case the user selects "Yes", along with any other data that you want to display in the prompt.

Here is example:

```
function promptForDelete(rowId){
    $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
            .html('<div><h6>Delete duplicate?</h6></div>')
            .dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: 'Delete message',
                zIndex: 10000,
                autoOpen: true,
                width: 'auto',
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    Yes: function () {
                        deleteRow(rowId);
                        blnAdd = 1;
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    No: function () {
                        blnAdd = 0;
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
}
```

Now for the second function "deleteRow" all you have to do is find the row that matches that id and remove it.

Here is an example:

```
function deleteRow(rowId){
     $(rowId).remove();
}
```

And that's it.... I hope this makes sense to you.